# SPFX and Workbench IE11

Tags: spfx

I get the following error when trying to run spfx on IE 11 in workbench On-Premise

@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
File: fabricmdl2icons-2.23.ttf

webpart wont' load in IE but works good in chrome

Any ideas or workarounds to get spfx to work on IE 11 workbench?

Comment: can you post your code so we can try? or even better link to github repo?

Comment: You don't even need any code, just browsing to the workbench on-premises displays the same errors: _layouts/15/workbench.aspx  , without even any webpart on the page

whoops, illegal rule inserted @-o-keyframes  and also

Warning!
Use of this tool exposes you to potential security threats which can result in others gaining access to your personal Office 365 data (documents, emails, conversations and more). Make sure you trust the person or organization that asked you to access this tool before proceeding.

Comment: Oh I see, you're referring to the workbench inside of sharepoint, not local workbench E.G. `localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html` right?

Comment: yeah but even when I deploy to SharePoint onpremises the  console is full of the same errors, I think they released a fix for Sharepoint online but what about on premise, I'm wondering if there is a fix for onpremise since it is annoying to the other developers and our cyber team is freaking out about it a little

Comment: just adding an empty spfx webpart generates all the same errors

Comment: it's definitely something in the spfx framework

Comment: Sorry, can't help to that. I don't have an on prem environment ready to test with.